# C++ Add random characters into a string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, random, character

So I want to create 1000 words with a length of 5 random characters.  In my main I have word[1000] but when I try to run this code, it gives me an error saying "Expression:string subscript out of range".  I'm not sure why it does that because I thought string arrays were 2 dimensional?  If anyone could tell me why my code is wrong I'd appreciate it.  Thanks.

```
void createText(string w[], int seed) {
char ch;
srand(seed);
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        ch = ('A' + rand() % 26);
        w[i][j] = ch;
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    cout << w[i];
}
cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Most probably some issue with either `w[i][j] = ch;` or `cout << w[i];`. Debug yourself please, SO isn't a online debugging service!

Answer (score 0):

If an array is bidimensional, you can't print its values like w[i]. You must print always keeping in mind that the array is bidimensional, which means that the output must be done like cout << w[i][j];

In addition, you're passing an array of strings as an argument, and what you're doing is add characters to every single position, which means that you won't actually have nothing but 1000 characters inserted into that string (because you actually added "one-char" strings), so you'll only put 200 words with a length of 5 characters each one. Insert strings directly, and you'll get your 1000 words, but first find a way to build strings with random characters.

Something like:

for(conditions){

for(conditions){
build a word
}

array[x][y] = string
}

I guess it is similar to what you intended to do

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the array w does not have 1000 elements, also remember that here you will get a copy of `string w[]`. Better would be passing a pointer to w `(string* w)`, then You will have very clearly what is wrong. remember also that cout writes the string out untill it reaches a `'\0'` character, this also might be the cause. Quick session with [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/) will help:

```
gdb program
...
run
bt full
```

should pinpoint Your problem. if it's some kind of IDE, learn how to debug in it. Valgrind or some other memcheck like visual leak detector or luke stackwalker will also show you some tips about bad initialization or unmentioned memory leaks.